# Error Access to the path is denied when Rename a Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to rename the a folder with the new name inputed in a Textbox `txtFilenFolderName`:

```
   protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string[] values = EditValue;

            string oldpath = values[0];// = "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder"

            string oldName = values[2]; //= New Folder

            string newName = txtFilenFolderName.Text; //= New Folder1
            string newPath = string.Empty;


            if (oldName != newName)
            {                
                    newPath = oldpath.Replace(oldName, newName);
                    Directory.Move(oldpath, newPath);              
            }
            else 
                 lblmessage2.Text = "New name must not be the same as the old ";
        }
    }
```

Try to debug:

```
oldpath = "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder"
 oldName = New Folder
newName= New Folder1
newpath = "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder1"
```

Everything seems right, but I when I click on buton Edit ---> rename---> Update---> an error occur: `Access to the path is denied D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder`

Help!

Answer (score 0):

the path `"D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder"` probably doesn't exist.  I'm thinking you meant `"D:\C#Projects\website\Lecturer\giangvien\New folder"`.  I think what @CharmingInferno was trying to get at was that when you use `@` in front of  a string you don't need to use escape characters as it takes the text as is like the following

```
string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt";   // \\server\share\file.txt
string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";      // \\server\share\file.txt
```

However you are putting your values in the `EditValue` string array should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now.

Using

```
Directory.Move(srcDirectory, dstDirectory);
```

sometimes caused the `Access to the path /dstDirectory/ is denied` exception, sometimes it don't.

The following solved for me.

```
new DirectoryInfo(srcDirectory).MoveTo(dstDirectory);
```